# Generating UML Entity-Relationship Diagrams in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, diagrams, metauml

Would you recommend LaTeX for this kind of UML diagramming?

http://yuml.me/ is great for quickly drawing Use Case and Class diagrams.

Please recommend a library of some sort for LaTeX, or alternatively a non-LaTeX text-generated UML-diagramming tool which support Entity-Relationship Modelling.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your preference you could use either

- [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks)

  View the [examples gallery](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples) for an extract of the types of diagrams you can create under this Postscript-driven language. Specific to your request, you may find the following of interest

  - [Trees](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-tree/pst-tree)
  - [Flow chart](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-node/psmatrix/psmatrix#flowchart)
  - [UML diagrams](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/uml)
- [`pgf/tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

  Consider viewing [this example diagram](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pgf-umlsd/), or reading the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) on CTAN.
- [`metaUML`](http://metauml.sourceforge.net/old/index.html)

  Consider reading this [short guide](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/%7Egwiener/software-engineering/how-to-embed-uml-in-latex/), or the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/metauml/doc/metauml_manual_0.2.5.pdf) on CTAN.
- [UML](http://ctan.org/pkg/uml)

  Consider reading the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/uml/uml.pdf) on CTAN.